# How to Integrate website with Talentlms API

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

When I used this jQuery script to get resources from `Talentlms` through their API

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://aaaaa.bbb.com/api/v1/users",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "authorization": "Basic 5555555555555144455",//this for Api key + pw using basic authentication
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        
    }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

After executing this I am getting following error MSG in web browser console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>
> (Unauthorized) userProfile.aspx:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>
> https://aaaaa.bbb.com/api/v1/users. Response for preflight has invalid
>
> HTTP status code 401

Please give me a solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue while writing the code in Java, I was able to resolve it by appending a `:` after the API Key and encoding it in Base64 before sending it as Authorization header in HttpRequest:

```
    String theUrl = "https://xxxx.talentlms.com/api/v1/users";
    String apiKey = apiKeyFromWebsiteAccount + ":"; 
    String apiKeyEncoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(apiKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    try {
        org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient httpclient =
                new org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(theUrl);
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + apiKeyEncoded);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + e);
    }
```